# With WCF Service, How can i allow access to everyone to a particular page?

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services, wcf

I need to give anonymous access to particular methode within single WCFservice.

In my application i have multiple WCF Service:

First one is authentication.svc => all requests wil be redirect to this service   specialy to the "login" method.

I have to add a new WCF Service (register.svc) that wil be accessible for all user.

To do this i procceded like this:
To deny anonymous user to access entire wcf service:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="Authentication.svc/json/Login" timeout="30" />
</authentication> 
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

I add in my web.config file those line to allow access to everyone to registration WCF service :

```
<location path="RegistrationService.svc/json/Register" >
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

The problem is, when i want to access to the registration service i will be redirected to the authetication service!!

Any help, it will be great !!

Comment: User <location> tag to define the areas for allowed users.

Comment: I tried with <location> tag but I got the same problem